# Visual studio - TabControl.TabPages.Insert not working

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

Here's my code:

```
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyServiceSettings obj = (MyServiceSettings)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("MyServiceSettings");

        foreach (MyServiceConfigElement service in obj.Services)
            CreateServiceControl(service);
    }

    private void CreateServiceControl(MyServiceConfigElement service)
    {
        TabPage tp = new TabPage(service.Name);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(0, tp);
        //tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
        tabControl1.Refresh();    
    }
```

In a nutshell, it reads a section in a config file and creates a tab for each element in the section.

I already have one static TabPage created at design time. I want the dynamic created tabs to be inserted before this static tab.

Running this code, the tabcontrol shows only the static tabpage.

If I do this change:

```
        private void CreateServiceControl(SoftInfoServiceConfigElement service)
    {
        TabPage tp = new TabPage(service.Name);
        //tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(1, tp);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
        tabControl1.Refresh();
    }
```

Using the Add method shows all the pages. But I do not get the order I want.

Is there something I don't understand with the Insert method? Why is it'n working?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is a comment on [social.msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/5d10fd0c-1aa6-4092-922e-1fd7af979663) - although I could not find anything like this in the documentation:

> The TabControl's handle must be created for the Insert method to work

Try the mentioned code

```
IntPtr h = this.tabControl1.Handle;
```

before you loop over your services

Comment: Probably a bit cleaner would be: `tabControl1.CreateControl();` This would get rid of the dummy variable `h` and possibly also a code analysis warning.

P.S.: It's amazing that 5 year old SO questions & answers are still applicable today. ;-)

Comment: Moving the call out of the constructor and into the form's Load() method also takes care of this.

Comment: @Tobias, I just tried to use `.CreateControl()` instead of `.Handle` but it does not work. The new pages is still not inserted.

Comment: Sorry, @PhilS, but it's too long ago since I last worked with WinForms and I'm not into that problem anymore, so I fear I cannot help you here.

Answer (score 6):

Since "*[Brad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/362536/brad) is looking for a canonical answer*", I focus on answering the OP's question: "*Is there something I don't understand with the Insert method? Why isn't it working?*".

***It's a bug.***
The `Insert` method doesn't work if the TabControl handle is not created; however the `Add` method always works as expected, no matter the handle is created or not. It could be avoided with a correct implementation.

***This is how .NET Tab control works:*** it has been created based on the native [TabControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tab-controls?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235), which shows a list of tab headers and provide a [display area](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tab-controls?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#display-area) to show some contents inside the control. The .NET Implementation takes care of adding those headers to the native control and also keep a list of containers (TabPages) and position them correctly and show them [when user selects a tab](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,1b31148fc95aa30d).

***How the bug occurs for the Insert method but not for the Add method?***
If the .NET implementation doesn't add the tab page to the native TabControl using native methods, then it doesn't show the headers; And it's what happening here:
In the [Insert](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,c5b270144560e5f5) method, when the handle is not created, the .NET code doesn't call the native methods to add the tab page to the native control. Same for `Add` method; however the `Add` method, always works as expected, no matter if the handle is created or not, because in the `Add` method, the the .NET code checks if the control handle is not created, then it adds the tab page into a list of pages and later [when the control handle is created](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,e389c84196fbad4b), is calls the native API methods for all the pages in the collection; but for the [Insert](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,c5b270144560e5f5) method, when the handle is not created, they have not added the tab page to the list of tab pages.

**If you want to trace the code yourself,** look into the source code of [Insert](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,c5b270144560e5f5) and [Add](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,7bc75a420d7bf90b), and also consider looking into the custom implementation of the [ControlCollection](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,e87d0fbf34561a29) for the TabControl, especially the [Add](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabControl.cs,0da9ba2c7273a7da) method of it and pay attention to the `InsertingItem` and `IsHandleCreated` properties.

**And finally, how to avoid this situation?** Well, the accepted answer works properly, but if you don't like having a dummy line of code to get the handle of the control, you can do either of the following:

- You can call the insert in `OnShown` method or in `Shown` event handler of the form.
- You can also call the `Show` method of the form before inserting tab pages.
- You can reverse your list of configs and `Add` them to the control.
- You can add all the tab pages to an array, reverse the array and use `AddRange`.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the same index to the `Insert()` method. If you wish to simply increment, this should work:

```
// ...

int i = 0;
foreach (MyServiceConfigElement service in obj.Services)
            CreateServiceControl(service, i++);

// ...

private void CreateServiceControl(MyServiceConfigElement service, int i)
{
        TabPage tp = new TabPage(service.Name);
                tabControl1.TabPages.Insert(i, tp);
// ...

}
```